# Login and Logout authentication button to change from 'Login' to 'Logout' on main view controller, looking for best practices

Tags: swift, firebase, xcode10.1

first of all.... I am new to developing in swift 4.0 / Xcode 10.1. the design problem I am having is that I have created a login page with firebase authentication (which works) and I am currently trying to find out the best practices to set this up so that my 'login' button located in the top right of the page changes to 'logout' once the firebase authentication process has been for-filled. I have attached an image which should help. I can't seem to find any documentation on best practices for this type of thing...
[image: Image Here]

my guess would be that I setup a second view controller but 'protected' once the user has been authenticated. however, im asking this question in case there is an alternate / better way to complete this which I am not aware of?

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    } else {
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        authUI!.delegate = self
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIGoogleAuth()]

        authUI?.providers = providers
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
        self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


}
```

// added variable for login button as a boolean value and then added  button for values if login is true and false. Im now looking for assistance on how to then call the login function above. apologies I am very new to swift 4.0. any assistance is greatly appreciated

```
    @IBAction func pressedNavButtonRight(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if isLogin
    {isLogin = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem! = UIBarButtonItem(title: 
"Logout", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, 
action:"pressedNavButtonRight")
    }
    else
    {
        isLogin = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem! = UIBarButtonItem(title: 
"Login", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, 
 action:"pressedNavButtonRight")
    }
}
```

Comment: If all else is the same in that view controller, why not just change the button title and target whenever the user logs in/out?

Comment: I have added variable for login button as a boolean value and then added button for values if login is true and false. Im now looking for assistance on how to then call the login function above (login with firebase and google as seen in the first code extract). apologies I am very new to swift 4.0. any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: I’m also using multiple view controllers so I cannot use the first suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved, I figured it out. I was able to use a Boolean value to get the desired results. I might post the code later for anyone that is interested